# Swift collection view selections

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I got a collection view of photos, how can I limit the number of photos that users selected. e.g. The users can select up to 3 photos in the collection view

Answer (score 1):

This woked for me. I have build two methods one for `handleMultipleCellSelection` to check the max selected number of items  and one other for `handleCellSelection`.

This method  `handleMultipleCellSelection`  is called in    `didSelectItemAt` of `UICollectionViewDelegate`

```
var selectedServicesId = NSMutableArray()

  func handleMultipleCellSelection(_ cell: UICollectionViewCell, indexPath: IndexPath){
        if self.selectedServicesId.count < 3 {
            self.handleCellSelection(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
        }else{
            if  self.selectedServicesId.contains(servicesData!.data[indexPath.row].id){
                handleCellSelection(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
            }else{

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Attention", message: "You can not select more than three items", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .destructive, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

func handleCellSelection(_ cell: UICollectionViewCell, indexPath: IndexPath){
    if cell.backgroundColor == UIColor.white{

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#FFB74D")
        self.selectedServicesId.add(servicesData!.data[indexPath.row].id)
        self.searchView.alpha = 1
    }else{
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.selectedServicesId.remove(servicesData!.data[indexPath.row].id)
        if selectedServicesId.count == 0{
            self.searchView.alpha = 0
        }
    }
}
}
```

and in your `didSelectItemAt`:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell
        handleMultipleCellSelection(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the selected items into a new array and check for the count of the array to not exceed 3 items.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     if alreadyAddedItemArray.count == 3 {
        // replace the selected indexPath item with last added item
        // or any logic you prefer
     }
     else {
       // append new item to alreadyAddedItemArray.
     }
}
```